# C++ Shell Context Menu Extension

Tags: c++, windows, shell-extensions

I try to create a context menu extension for windows files/folders. I´ve already tried very much, but nothing worked for me. I already have such an extension for 32-Bit systems, but it´s outdated. I want to recreate it using C++ for 64-Bit systems.

This one was closest to what I want to do: [Klick](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/shellextguide1.aspx#gettingstarted)
But this is for 32-Bit systems. After reading the comments, I was able to modify&build it for x64.

Registering it using the system32/regsvr32.exe on my 64-Bit system, tells that it was successfully registered. All the registry entries are created correctly. But the menu item does not appear. I have no clue why...

Can someone help me? I can upload the project for you if you want.

**UPDATE**

I use the original Project from the link above and changed the following things:

1) set target to "x64"

2) since I couln't compile it, i changed the following things:

2.1) Before the includes in stdafx.h I added:

```
#define _ATL_NO_UUIDOF
```

2.2) I changed UINT to UINT_PTR here:

```
HRESULT CFSBankShellExtension::GetCommandString (
UINT_PTR idCmd, 
UINT uFlags, 
UINT* pwReserved,
LPSTR pszName, 
UINT cchMax )
```

3) I changed txtfile to * in the .rgs file, so that it should apper on all filetypes.

4) I was able to compile and register it

If you can´t help me, it would be cool if you could upload a template, that will work on x64 system.

Comment: First step is to find out if your dll has actually loaded into the explorer process. Try using the SysInternals procexp tool and switching on the bottom pane DLL View.

Comment: It´s there! I searched for SimpleExt.dll and found it in the procexp too. So... what next?

Comment: Are you using Visual Studio? Load up your project, attach the VS debugger to explorer.exe and set breakpoint in your extension's methods. Then right click on something and see if your functions are actually being called. If they are called, step through them and try to find out where they go wrong.

Comment: Not even a single function is called...

Comment: @FlashFan: If it's loaded, you can be entirely certain that `DllMain()` is called, and with 99.9x% certainty your `QueryInterface()` is also called. That's just basic COM stuff. But do you respond properly? 32 bits Windows has quite some legacy hacks on which you may inadvertently rely.

Comment: I don´t know how "attaching to a process" exactly works, but it could be, that the DllMain is marked as "not called", because it is only called when explorer.exe starts, or when I register my dll. I´ve added some functions that create files in all methods. The file from the DllMain was created after registering. All other files not. Not even the file from the constructor of the class... I´ll update my question and tell you what excatly I have changed on the project.

Comment: You need to actaully debug your shell extension to see what is going wrong. Set a breakpoint on `DllGetClassObject` and follow it from there. It may be easier to debug notepad.exe and open your shell extension from the File.Open dialog, rather than trying to debug Explorer.

Comment: Ok, I could debug it. DllGetClassObject is CALLED! But in this method, there's an exception that comes from line 99 in atlcore.h. It's an empty exception...

Answer (score 0):

This article might help you as it worked out for my project..

[Simple shell context menu](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/shell/SimpleContextMenu.aspx)

> Context menus for all files, folders, and drives
>
> You can also hookup context menus to all files, folders, and drives by
>   adding entries to the file type's *, Directory, and Drive registry
>   keys. For example, XP PowerToys adds the Open Command Window Here menu
>   to all folders with the following registry script:
>
> REGEDIT4
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd] @="Open Command Window Here"
>
> [HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell\cmd\command] @="cmd.exe /k \"cd
>   %L\""

Comment: Thanks, but this is not flexible enough for me. I want, that the menu item even appears, when I select multiple files/folders and then right click on them. I want to detect all selected files, and then (based on conditions) decide if the menu item should appear or not. So i need to create a DLL for it.